# Find file in Perl — skip permission denied

Tags: file, perl, find

Trying to use the Perl script below to find script full path in sub-directories.  It needs to skip the permission denied folders, whereas it is failing in a certain sub-directory if permission is denied.

How can I continue after a 'permission denied' problem?

```
use File::Find;

my @files;
my @dirpath=qw(/app/welogic/);
 find(sub {
           push @files,$File::Find::name if (-f $File::Find::name      and /\wlst.sh$/);
      }, @dirpath);
```

Comment: When I run the script you show, adapted to process my directory structure and look for my files, I get error messages about inaccessible directories, but the code continues to look in other directories after that.  I'm using Perl 5.28.2, (on a Mac running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave) if that helps at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also find that that is indeed only a warning, but the search does fail to produce results (v5.16 and v5.30).  However, once `chdir`-ing is disabled in options then it all works. I don't know why.

Comment: I added to my answer another, cleaner, way to solve this (by `preprocess`-ing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Permission denied` (for `cd`) is only a warning for me (managed using a `$SIG{__WARN__}` hook as below), so the program isn't getting killed.

However, the search does get hampered, I suspect by the fact that in [`find` operation](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

> Additionally, for each directory found, it will `chdir()` into that directory and continue the search, invoking the `&wanted` function on each file or subdirectory in the directory.

and apparently once this `chdir` is foiled the search fails and I get no results.  (Note added -- on another system the search works, except for the no-no directory of course and with the warning.  But this clearly needs fixing.)

I see two ways around this: use `preprocess` option to filter out directories, or disable `chdir`.

**— Use `preprocess` option to filter out directories with bad permissions**

The `preprocess` option invokes a user given subroutine, which receives the list of entries (in the current directory, to be processed) and should return a list, of entries that will then be processed.

So we can check the input list of entries (in `@_`) for directories with bad permissions and exclude them from the return list, so they are never attempted

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

my @dirpath = @ARGV ? @ARGV : die "Usage: $0 dir-list\n";

my @files;

find( { 
    wanted => sub { 
        push @files, $File::Find::name 
            if -f $File::Find::name and /\.txt$/ 
    },  
    preprocess => sub { 
        #say "--> Reading: $File::Find::dir";         
        return grep { not (-d and (not -x or not -r)) } @_; 
    }
}, @dirpath); 

say for @files;
```

In the `return` statement we filter out directories that are non-executable or unreadable.  See [-X (filetest) operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). That statement can be rewritten to print names for logging etc.

**— Disable the `chdir`-ing, via the `no_chdir` option**

When `chdir` to the directory (before listing its contents) is suppressed the search works overall. I don't know why the whole search fails with `chdir` but works without it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn "WARN: @_" };  # manage the warnings

sub bad_perm {
    push @files, $File::Find::name 
        if (-f $File::Find::name and /\.txt$/);
};

my @dirpath = @ARGV ? @ARGV : die "Usage: $0 dir-list\n";

my @files;

find( { no_chdir => 1, wanted => \&bad_perm }, @dirpath );

say for @files;
```

Now the search runs fine and assembles the correct list of (`.txt`) files.

Along with that a warning is printed, now for `opendir`

```
Can't opendir(tmp/this_belongs_to_root): Permission denied
```

The warning can be manipulated as you please in the `$SIG{__WARN__}` subroutine.  If you don't want to see this warning then re-emit warnings for all else except it, for example by

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { 
    warn @_  unless $_[0] =~ /^Can't opendir\(.*?: Permission denied/;
};
```

See [%SIG variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

---

I check both ways with a small hierarchy of files and directories made for this purpose, which contain a directory made by root with `chmod go-rwx` permissions (for which I duly get errors whichever way I try to touch it as a user).

I also tweak `-x` / `-r` permissions on yet other directories and the code works as intended.